LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "class Point __cdecl point(void)" (?point@@YA?AVPoint@@XZ) в функции main
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class Point {
public:
    int x, y, z;
    Point() {
        x = y = z = 0;
    }
    Point(int x, int y, int z) {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        this->z = z;
    }
};

ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Point& point) {
    os << point.x << " " << point.y << " " << point.z << endl;
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    Point point();
    cout << point();
    fstream file("FILE.TXT", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app);
    if (file) {
        file << point();
    }
    else cout << "Не открылось(";

    file.close();
    return 0;
}

В Visual Studio выходит 2 ошибки:
LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "class Point __cdecl point(void)" (?point@@YA?AVPoint@@XZ) в функции main
LNK1120 неразрешенных внешних элементов: 1

Вы, по сути, объявили функцию Point point(); и пытаетесь её вызывать. Уберите везде скобочки у point
